# How to Access Multiple Array inside one Object Using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am getting one object from siebel which consists of multiple array. I don't know about the elements those array holds but I want to iterate through the whole object and get the property and corresponding values from it. How can I do it using javascript/jQuery?

When I converted the object to its source it gave me the following code:

```
({childArray:[{childArray:[{childArray:[{childArray:[{childArray:[], childEnum:0, propArray:[], propArrayLen:0, type:"ListOfFS Instruction", value:"", axObj:null}], childEnum:0, propArray:[], propArrayLen:24, type:"Action", value:"", axObj:null}], childEnum:0, propArray:[], propArrayLen:0, type:"ListOfHW OUI Activity Summary", value:"", axObj:null}], childEnum:0, propArray:[], propArrayLen:4, type:"SiebelMessage", value:"", axObj:null}], childEnum:0, propArray:[], propArrayLen:5, type:"ResultSet", value:"", axObj:null})
```

Please help..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a Siebel property set. You can use standard methods like enumChild on these objects to obtain desired values. Please see below

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/config_open_ui/appendix_a_API24.html